# Index was outside the bounds of the array. Login+<LoginPlayer>d__4.MoveNext () (at Assets/Login.cs:29)

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I'm building a system in Unity that takes a register and login menu connected to a MySQL database through PHPMyAdmin, has users log in, then allows them to choose between playing two games. I've been getting this error since I linked the games and I can't figure out how to fix it. The register works fine, but it won't allow for log in.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;


public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField nameField;
    public TMP_InputField passwordField;

    public Button submitButton;

    public void CallLogin()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoginPlayer());
    }

    IEnumerator LoginPlayer()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", nameField.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);

        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login.php", form);
        yield return www;

        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {
            dbmanager.username = nameField.text;
            dbmanager.score = int.Parse(www.text.Split('\t')[1]);
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Login failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }
    }

    public void VerifyInputs()
    {
        submitButton.interactable = (nameField.text.Length >= 8 && passwordField.text.Length >= 8);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out what happened for hours and need some extra insight, can anyone please help?

[image: This is the php code if that helps at all.]

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). What debugging have you done? Is it the response from PHP that looks strange? Have you tested calling it directly through Postman or something?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.